Hide portion of document but spare references
I have a document with a main and supplemental portion. The journal I am submitting to wants my document to generate the main portion only, without the supplement. However, if I just get rid of the supplement from the main .tex file, it'll bork all the references to the supplement in the main document. Therefore, I want to hide the supplement without actually removing the content.

Welcome to tex.sx.  I think this has already been addressed, but don't have time now to look for the reference.  If you keep the supplement as a separate file and include or exclude it with \includeonly, compiling the whole document will result in an .aux file for each included file, and when later excluding the supplement, the .aux file will still be read, and the cross-references will be included without the supplement itself.

This is helpful. However, the tyrannical arbitrary journal I'm submitting to, a Nature subject journal, wants everything in a single .tex file (rather than using \include to keep the supplement as an extra file). Is there a way to exclude text and have it be in the same document?

That's a tougher problem, and I can't think of an easy workaround.   I don't think marking the supplement as a comment after the initial run would work because the Nature processing would no doubt fail to accept the need for a second (changed) run.  I hope someone else can come up with a workable approach.
